# Use offline datatables files instead of the cdn

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I am planning on minifying the css in my project and I am trying to remove the files from cdn and replace them with offline files

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.css"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.0.0/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

The first url also happens to include `twitter-bootstrap` which I have already included on the page. I have tried to replace the `cdn styles` with the following from the `datatables Download builder page`:

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/jquery.dataTables.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/dataTables.bootstrap.css"/>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="css/responsive.bootstrap.css"/>
```

However I find that the styles are not applied correctly. Is this the appropriate styles to include or should I add any other css files.

Answer (score 1):

open the links in a Browser

```
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="https://cdn.datatables.net/r/bs-3.3.5/jq-2.1.4,dt-1.10.8/datatables.min.css"/>
<link href="https://cdn.datatables.net/responsive/2.0.0/css/responsive.bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
```

copy all contents

save the contents to a css file

and link to it

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="theplacewhereistored/that.css"/>
```

alternate if you donwloaded the files, youre pointing to the wrong place, maybe youre missing a "/" to make path relative from domain root